# How to access external USB cameras using Android cameraX?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I was following this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started) to create a cameraX application .

It's working fine in my phone .
But the app I am developing is for an android media player.Which doesn't have any inbuilt camera , only an external usb cam is attached .

This is my code to start the camera.

```
private void startCamera() {
    ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.getSurfaceProvider());
    imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder().build();
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
                try {
                    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                    cameraProvider.unbindAll();
                    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,preview,imageCapture);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)
    );


}
```

it's throwing **IllegalArgumentException** saying no camera connected .

in `cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,preview,imageCapture);`

only `CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA` and `CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA`
available.

How to access an external camera ?

[Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera&hl=en_IN&gl=US) app from play store is working fine .

Comment: OpenCamera is open source. Why don't you just check the source code of the app yourself how they access the camera?

Comment: AFAIK, CameraX does not support external cameras (USB or otherwise) at this time.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/code/ci/master/tree/app/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/opencamera/cameracontroller/CameraController2.java#l20    They are using Camera2 Apis . I was looking for a cameraX solution .

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay .

Comment: I wonder if you'd be able to do it by building a custom `CameraSelector` using `CameraSelector.Builder().addCameraFilter()`, where the `CameraFilter` chooses the camera id of your external camera. You can get the camera id using Camera2 interop:  `Camera2CameraInfo.from(cameraInfo).getCameraId()`.

Comment: @AravindOR have you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: @SejpalsinhJadeja No .. like CommonsWare said ," CameraX does not support external cameras (USB or otherwise) at this time."
 I used camera 2 apis and it worked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve the issue, you can find my project code in this site:

[reference JavaApplication Module](https://github.com/HOLDfoot/CameraXBasic.git)

I create a filter:

```
@SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
class MyCameraFilter implements CameraFilter {

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public LinkedHashSet<Camera> filter(@NonNull LinkedHashSet<Camera> cameras) {
        Log.i(TAG, "cameras size: " + cameras.size());
        Iterator<Camera> cameraIterator = cameras.iterator();
        Camera camera = null;
        while (cameraIterator.hasNext()) {
            camera = cameraIterator.next();
            String getImplementationType = camera.getCameraInfo().getImplementationType();
            Log.i(TAG, "getImplementationType: " + getImplementationType);
        }
        LinkedHashSet linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        linkedHashSet.add(camera); // 最后一个camera
        return linkedHashSet;
    }
}
```

and pass it to CameraSelector:

```
cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder().addCameraFilter(new MyCameraFilter()).build();
```

Now i can access usb camera. My develop android chip is Android API 11
The log "cameras size: " will tell you how many cameras connected to the usb. Default select the last camera.

Comment: This gives me a NPE inside PreviewView, on version 1.1.0

Comment: thank you for your source code i have tried this source code in Redmi note 7s ,redmi note  7a , and moto E still its not working "cameras size:  2" stills hoes 2 my front and back camera  but not my EXternal USB camera. but the usb camera is working fine in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shenyaocn.android.usbcamera in this app. is there anything else or am i missing something?

Comment: In the current implementation of CameraFilter (CameraX 1.3.0) there is no method `LinkedHashSet<Camera> filter(@NonNull LinkedHashSet<Camera> cameras)`

Comment: @Alexey: The current filter interface is List<CameraInfo> filter(@NonNull List<CameraInfo> cameraInfos) -- CameraInfo instead of Camera and List instead of LinkedHashSet. Easy enough to make those changes. but .... getImplementationType is resticted to LIBRARY_GROUP; not public :(

Answer (score 2):

As of now CameraX does not support the external usb camera. Instead of CameraX you can use Camera 2 API.

Comment: can you provide any doc for that?

Comment: @snachmsm you can track it in google's issuetracker which officially states as so:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162382076?pli=1

that being said there is a workaround as mentioned above (and in that issuetracker) https://stackoverflow.com/a/73061654/159825

Comment: I used to think so. but some manufacturer can make the firmware can choose camera. If who meet the problem can at least have a try.