# View external USB camera image on PreviewView in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-usb

Is there a way to pass `SurfaceView` as the `SurfaceProvider` for a `Preview` in Android?

I have two Fragments, each one has a `PreviewView` to display the Camera feed of the following Cameras on my Android device:

1. `DeviceFragment` -> Displays built-in camera feed
2. `UsbCameraFragment` -> Should display the attached USB device camera feed

`PreviewView` on Fragment #1 works just fine as I think it's meant to display the Device camera right away.

But `PreviewView` on Fragment #2, no matter what I do, won't display the USB Camera feed. It only displays the built-in Device camera feed.
So, in order to be sure my USB Camera feed is working, I setup a `SurfaceView` on that Fragment et voilà, my USB feed is displayed correctly on that.

Is there a way to change the default behavior of `PreviewView` so it displays my USB camera instead of the Device's?

My final goal is to process the camera feed via the `CameraProvider.bindToLifecycle()` method. To achieve this, I created a `Preview` object and set `PreviewView.getSurfaceProvider()` as its surfaceProvider. But I can't achieve the same using a `SurfaceView` as it has no methods that return a surfaceProvider.

Here's a snippet of the method I created on my `UsbCameraFragment` that could help understanding:

```
private void bindCamera(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
    ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = imageAnalysisService.bindImageAnalysis(surfaceView); // I don't think it's relevant right now. Can share later if needed.
    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider()); // Here's where I would like to use my SurfaceView OR parse it to PreviewView
    CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();

    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis);
}
```

NOTES:

- Commenting out `preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());` makes my `SurfaceView` be displayed and it doesn't get overlapped by the `PreviewView`
- Keeping it as it, the `SurfaceView` is displayed for a brief second and then it gets overlapped by the Device Camera's image (rendered by the `PreviewView`)
- I tried adding a filter to the `CameraSelector` object, but then I have another problem: The Usb Camera is not listed among all available cameras.

Comment: Related: [How to access external USB cameras using Android cameraX?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71688837/295004)